# Crystal Report Does not display properly - Invalid Index

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in my project. Whenever I am trying to open that page, This exception appear.

> Crystal Report: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

In my Crystal Report, I have a Parameter Fields named `isEffective (Boolean type).` When I run the program and the debug point hit `report1.SetParameterVlaue`, this exception appear. However, when I comment this line, there is no exception.

```
Report report1 = Report();
report1.SetParameterValue("isEffective", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
report1.SetParameterValue("@isEffective", true);
```

Some time this error occurs when your parameters not matched in both reports & coding. May be your parameter name is wrong. So verify the parameters & parameter names are same in report & your coding.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried that and check again with my parameter name in the Crystal Report. The parameter name in the CR match the name in my code (isEffective) but the error still there

Comment: did you add the @ sign before your parameter??

Comment: Yes, I did, still have the same problem

Comment: When I break down and look into my report1. I see that the report1's Parameter Fields Count = 0.